# Delphi 7 Edit Box Digit Grouping With Commas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, digits, editbox

I've been doing research a lot, still have no clue in how to display numerical (esp. monetary figures with two commas or cents) input as digit grouped input i.e ONE MILLION = 1000000.25 to 1,000,000.25 directly via OnChange or OnKeyPress in Delphi 7.

i don't want to use command button to change, i want it to behave like windows 7 calculator input box (via OnChange,OnKeyPress). it has digit grouping and it has commas (dot).

If i look at the windows 7 calculator input box and activate the digit grouping, that is how i also want my edit box in delphi 7 behave. is there any approach or solution for this?

Comment: Windows Calculator does not have an edit box that you directly type into, it uses button presses and intercepted keystrokes to track the user's input, and then displays the calculated number in a display box using a function that is equivalent to Delphi's `SysUtils.FormatCurr()` function. If you want the grouping done on an actual edit field, use `TMaskEdit` instead of `TEdit`.

Comment: so it actually intercept the numeric pad, i actually manage to get onkeypress to work and the user can type 0 to 9 with only single dot (.) for commas, ie 10000.25, there will be no double dot allowed in the edit box. i just need to apply the digit grouping. 
if there's no workaround in this, then i have to use tmaskedit

Comment: Again, Calculator does not have an actual edit box, so it operates differently (and simpler) than what you are trying to do. If you really need to display digit grouping in a `TEdit`, try using its `OnChange` or `OnExit` event to call `value := StrToCurr(Edit.Text)` followed by either `Edit.Text := FormatCurr('#,##0.##', value)` or `Edit.Text := CurrToStrF(value, ffNumber, 2)` to parse the user's input and reformat it as needed.

Comment: i've tried your code as follows :
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
    var 
    value: currency;
    begin
    value := StrToCurr(Edit1.Text);
    Edit1.Text := FormatCurr('#,##0.##', value);
    end;

but as soon as i typed number it would raise EConvertError

and i've tried this one also
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var value: currency;
begin
  value := StrToCurr(Edit1.Text);
  Edit1.Text := CurrToStrF(value, ffNumber, 2);
end;

when i typed result in the same EConvertError
@RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1):

May be as easy as:

label1.caption := FormatFloat('#,###,###.00',10000000.25);

Greetings.
Pau.

Comment: thx but i need to alter the the format while it typed in editbox
@pau

Comment: procedure TForm2.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
   value:Extended;
   c:String;
begin
  FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator:='.';
  FormatSettings.ThousandSeparator:=',';
  c := StringReplace(Edit1.text,',','',[rfReplaceall]);
  Value := StrToFloat(c);
  Edit1.text := FormatFloat('#,###,###.##',Value);
end;

Comment: still doesn't work in delphi 7, cause everytime i type 4 digit number, then it would not allowed me enter more zero number in the back or the right, and then any number i type would start from the left not the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This code worked for me very well
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);   
var Valor: Double;  
begin  
  try          
     StrData := StrData + Key;   
     EliminarFormato(Trim(StrData));   
     Valor := StrToFloat(StrData);  
     Edit1.Text := Format('%8.0n',[Valor]);   
     Key := #03;  
     SendMessage(Edit1.Handle,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_END,0);     
   except on E: Exception do
     StrData := '';  
   end;   
end;

function TForm1.EliminarFormato(const Data: string): string;  
var Datos: string;   
    I: Word;  
begin
  Datos := Trim(Data);   
  repeat  
    I := Pos('.',Datos);  
    if I > 0 then  
      Delete(Datos,I,1);  
  until (Pos('.',Datos) = 0);    
  Result := Datos;  
end;
```